# Error with authentication while using Google's Node.js Sheets API: The provided keyfile does not define a valid redirect URI

Tags: node.js, google-sheets, google-api, google-oauth, google-sheets-api

I am trying to write to a google sheet using the Node.js Google Sheets API, but when I run the script, using the command quoted bellow, I get the following error:

> node append.js *Spreadsheet-ID* 0

```
Error: The provided keyfile does not define a valid
redirect URI. There must be at least one redirect URI defined, and this sample
assumes it redirects to 'http://localhost:3000/oauth2callback'.  Please edit
your keyfile, and add a 'redirect_uris' section.  For example:

"redirect_uris": [
  "http://localhost:3000/oauth2callback"
]

    at authenticate (/folder/node_modules/@google-cloud/local-auth/build/src/index.js:56:15)
    at runSample (/folder/append.js:24:22)
    at Object.<anonymous> (/folder/append.js:52:3)
    at Module._compile (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:778:30)
    at Object.Module._extensions..js (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:789:10)
    at Module.load (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:653:32)
    at tryModuleLoad (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:593:12)
    at Function.Module._load (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:585:3)
    at Function.Module.runMain (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:831:12)
    at startup (internal/bootstrap/node.js:283:19)
```

I am using the append.js script provided by Google in their [googleapis Github repository](https://github.com/googleapis/google-api-nodejs-client/blob/master/samples/sheets/append.js).

My oauth2.keys.json file:

```
{
    "web": {
        "client_id": "my-client-id.apps.googleusercontent.com",
        "project_id": "my-id",
        "auth_uri": "https://accounts.google.com/o/oauth2/auth",
        "token_uri": "https://oauth2.googleapis.com/token",
        "auth_provider_x509_cert_url": "https://www.googleapis.com/oauth2/v1/certs",
        "client_secret": "client_secret",
        "redirect_uris": [
            "https://my-site.net"
        ]
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

#### You need a *valid* redirect URI

I know, that's what the error says, I am sorry to just repeat that, however, it is the clue to what you are getting tripped up on.

After the application is successfully authorized the redirect URI can't just be `"https://my-site.net"`. The resource at the URI needs to be able to handle the OAuth2 response which will either contain an authorization code or an error response.

[Here](https://developers.google.com/identity/protocols/oauth2/web-server#handlingresponse) is a link to the Google guide for handling the server response.

[Here](https://github.com/googleapis/google-api-nodejs-client/issues/2254) is an issue from the Github Repo, linked because it is a good case study of someone who had a similar problem to yours and could help you out as you work out how to authenticate your application.

The [Oauth2 docs](https://developers.google.com/identity/protocols/oauth2) that Google provide have extensive information and guides to help.

Comment: I'm trying to follow the tutorial and have access from a desktop application to my Excel sheets on GDrive, which means I didn't mean to create any web service, but looks like there is no way without doing so, right? to specify the OAuth callback I need some service and moreover, I need to refer it in console, so also there I need to use Web service and not desktop since it doesn't have any point to specify the callback URI. Could you clarify it for me, please?

Comment: I'm not sure what you mean @LiudmilaDobriakova, maybe it's best to ask another question with full details and the code you have so far.

Comment: thanks for replying. I figured out the problem. The quick guide I was following suppose to be executed on the local PC, I was running the Node js code on the remote SSH terminal, that is why it was failing on authentication on my local PC browser.